# Make textbox multiline programmatically

Tags: c#, textbox, programmatically-created

I am creating my textbox within the runtime like this:

```
TextBox control = new TextBox();                        
control.Name = "txt" + "somename";
```

I searached on the internet and found that there should be a Multiline-Property in Textbox, but sadly I could not find it.
I tried also to add multiple lines, but this isn't working either.

How can I do it within my code?
I use Windowsforms and .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF/

Comment: Oh sorry, I use WinForms

Comment: What does *but sadly I could not find it* mean? If the Property exists, it's not really difficult to find it. Write `control`, enter a `dot` and Intellisense will kick in. Double check you Project Properties, maybe you have used the WPF template instead of Windows Forms by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
control.Multiline = true;
```

That will make your textbox multiline. Here is a fully working example:

```
var textBox = new TextBox
{
  Multiline = true
};

textBox.Text = "FirstLine" + Environment.NewLine + "SecondLine";
```

Comment: It cannot find the .Multiline property, that's my issue.
Is there another way/a fix?

Comment: Are you sure you are working in a windows forms project? Where did you write the code you provided in your question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline?view=net-5.0 - well, it does exist! Do you get a compiler error ? Show a screenshot

Comment: All I get is Error CS1061 "Control" does not contain a definition for "multiline", and no accessible multiline extension method could be found that accepts a first argument of type "Control" (possibly missing a using directive or assembly reference).

Comment: My Code:
                            `case "BIGTEXTBOX":
                            control = new TextBox();
                            control.Name = "txt" + name;
                            control.Multiline = true;
                            control.KeyPress += frm.textBox_KeyPress;
                            mdl.alertOnNull = true;
                            mdl.LabelAnchorOnTop = true;
                            break;`

Comment: @Joo Please post the entire method or class in your question.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks :D